# what code should i modify in this SpringBoot org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, error-handling

made a test code but failed,
the Error is :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSyIo.png)

and here's the test code

@Test
public void Posts_update() throws Exception {

```
    Posts savedPosts = postsRepository.save(Posts.builder()
            .title("title")
            .content("content")
            .author("author")
            .build());

    Long updateId = savedPosts.getId();
    String expectedTitle = "title2";
    String expectedContent = "content2";

    PostsUpdateRequestDto requestDto = PostsUpdateRequestDto.builder()
            .title(expectedTitle)
            .content(expectedContent)
            .build();

    String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/api/v1/posts/" + updateId;

    HttpEntity<PostsUpdateRequestDto> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestDto);

    // when
    ResponseEntity<Long> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, Long.class);

    // then
    assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    assertThat(responseEntity.getBody()).isGreaterThan(0L);

    List<Posts> all = postsRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(all.get(0).getTitle()).isEqualTo(expectedTitle);
    assertThat(all.get(0).getContent()).isEqualTo(expectedContent);
}
```

I'm trying this from a book but i can't find answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving entity with title "title" and expecting it to be "title2" when you fetch it. Either change your entity data or expected title. Replace repository save with below

```
Posts savedPosts = postsRepository.save(Posts.builder()
            .title("title2")
            .content("content")
            .author("author")
            .build());
```

This should work